# Direction and rate of increase of the function $f(\mathbf{x}) = x^2+y^2-4z^2$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Find the direction in which $f(\mathbf{x}) = x^2+y^2-4z^2$ is increasing
>   most rapidly at the point $(1, 1, 1)$. Also find this rate of
>   increase.

$\nabla f(\mathbf{x}) = (2x, 2y, -8z)$ and $\nabla f({1,1,1}) = (2, 2, -8)$ and $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1,1,1) \cdot(2,2,-8) = -\dfrac{4}{\sqrt{3}}$

What am I doing wrong? The answer given for the rate of increase is $6\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Did you calculate the directional derivative correctly?

Comment: you calculated the rate of increase in the direction $(1,1,1)$ The maximum rate of increase is in the direction $(2,2,-8)$ which has magnitude $$|\nabla f(1,1,1) |= 6\sqrt 2$$

Comment: @WW1 I see. Pardon my ignorance, but why is the rate of change maximum at the magnitude?

Comment: I think I see it. If we normalise $(2,2,-8)$ first then dot it with $\nabla f(1,1,1)$ it comes out. Many thanks.